# How is the syntax of Ruby's alias allowed?

Tags: ruby

This one's been keeping me up at night for a while.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end

  # What the hell is going on here?!?
  alias :baz :bar
end

Foo.new.baz #=> 'bar'
```

Why does `alias` take 2 symbol as arguments, but without a comma separating them? That doesn't seem to be any form of valid syntax in any other context.  And in fact, if you do use a comma, it actually *throws* a syntax error.

```
alias :bar, :baz
# syntax error, unexpected ','
```

However, if I try to pass 2 symbol in the same way to my own method, it also explodes:

```
def somemethod(*args)
  :whatever
end
somemethod :a :b
# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

1. So why is the `alias` method get to use a syntax nothing else gets to use?
2. Is it possible to use this syntax in any other context?
3. What is the benefit of using this odd syntax quirk, when nothing else in the language works this way? I see no discernable benefit to this language inconsistency.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason `alias` works is because it's a Ruby keyword, similar to `class`, `def`, etc. It's not a method.

The `alias` keyword doesn't need a comma because the Ruby designers decided it didn't. Keywords are essentially hardcoded in the interpreter.

There is a good reason for `alias` when you need to be certain the alias happens at parse time, not runtime.

The `alias` keyword may be confusing or surprising. For typical development, I believe it's better to use the Ruby method [`Module#alias_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method), which does use a comma and works at runtime.

[Here's a good blog post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html) about `alias` and `alias_method`:

> This is because `alias` is a keyword and it is lexically scoped. It
>   means it treats `self` as the value of `self` at the time the source code
>   was read. In contrast `alias_method` treats `self` as the value
>   determined at the run time.
>
> Overall my recommendation would be to use `alias_method`. Since
>   `alias_method` is a method defined in class `Module` it can be overridden
>   later and it offers more flexibility.

Comment: So because it's a keyword, it's allowed a special syntax which is hardcoded into the interpreter for just this case? That kind of smells.

Comment: @Alex, yes, it's hardcoded in the interpreter. There's a good reason for it for some programming needs because you can be certain the alias happens at read time, not runtime.

Comment: @AlexWayne: The same could be said about the `else` keyword, or the  `case` keyword. Do you really think it's a design smell for keywords to have their own specific syntaxes? I'd challenge you to find any high-level programming language where no keywords have their own syntax and they all behave exactly the same as method calls.

Comment: @Jazz Well, no, of course not. This one is just weird because it doesn't seem like it needs to be a keyword. And the syntax looks like a method invocation, save for a single comma. It's just sort of weird. But given you want `alias_method` most of the time anyway, it's sort of a moot point. Im over it :p

Answer (score 7):

It's not a method, and those aren't arguments. `alias` is one of the few keywords in Ruby (see them all [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/)!). It bothers me as well, so I switched to `alias_method` (and there are [other arguments for this](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html)).